# How can I find the initial state vector from state space model?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, system-identification

Assume that we have input $u(k)\in \Re $ and output $y(k) \in \Re$ and we estimate the black box model by using subspace identification method.

$$x (k+1) = Ax (k)  + Bu(k) $$
$$y (k) = Cx (k) $$

If we know $A \in \Re^{2x2} ,B \in \Re^{2x1},C  \in \Re^{1x2}$ and the input and output.

How can we find $x (k) \in \Re^{2}$ at $y (k) $ when $k > 0$ ?

Comment: Do we have any assumptions for the system (such as LTI?)? Also, do we know $y(k)$, $u(k)$, or even better the trajectory of previously applied $u$ and measured $y$?

Comment: @SteveHeim We start at $x (k) = 0$. We know the past trajectories. Can we use a Kalman filter for this ?

Comment: I'm very confused. I thought you are trying to find $x(0)$?

Comment: @SteveHeim yes I'm trying to do that.

Comment: But you say you start with $x(k) = 0$... I'm really confused what you know, what you are looking for etc.

Comment: @SteveHeim yes. But can we find $x (k) $ for all $k $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do not know the initial condition and/or have uncertainty and noise. Otherwise you can use the state equations to propagate the state vector. If the system is observable

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability,

then you can use an observer:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer.

If you have noise in the output and uncertainty in the model, you can use the Kalman filter:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

Better resource on KF:

http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf

If your system is not observable, then the state cannot be estimated from the information you have.